# How can we pass a number with forward slash "/" to codeigniter controller using ajax

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter

I have to call a `CodeIgniter` function from ajax call, I have a number as a parameter with slash **e.g 11/201**. I think CodeIgniter function take it as two parameters because of slash.

```
url: "<?php echo base_url() ?>uside/find/" +myno,
```

Comment: can't you pass it as a string?

Comment: you can pass it as GET or POST variable also if URL creating problem

Comment: Did you mean its a (`11/201`) single parameter?

Comment: Yes as a single parameter #AmanullahAman.

Comment: @DanishAli do you have an exmple about it?

Comment: @MansoorAhmed Yes let me answer.

Comment: What routes you have defined?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the / character in your config.php under allowed_char like this:

```
$config['permitted_uri_chars'] = 'a-z 0-9~%.:_\-=&';
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to send parameter in the form of `GET` or `POST` variable like this

```
 $.ajax({
     type: 'POST',
     data: {
        'variable1': 'value1',
        'variable2': 'value2'  
     },
     url: "your-url",
     dataType: 'json',
     success: function (data) {
     }
 });
```

**Controller**

In the controller, function get these variables like

```
 $variable1 = $this->input->post('variable1');
 $variable2 = $this->input->post('variable2');
```

For `GET` in the AJAX call

```
type: 'GET',
```

And in the controller

```
 $variable1 = $this->input->get('variable1');
 $variable2 = $this->input->get('variable2');
```

Comment: @MansoorAhmed now what is the issue with it?

Answer (score 0):

IF you wish access those variable with uri parameter then best way is

```
url: "<?php echo base_url() ?>uside/find/" +myno+'/'+var2+'/'+var3,
```